# Como baixar um arquivo de um URL utilizando C#?

Tags: c#, .net, download

Desenvolvendo um projeto em C# me deparei com a seguinte situação, estou precisando baixar arquivos de alguns URL's, qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Teria alguma maneira de juntamente ao download implementar uma barra de progresso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar o [`DownloadFileTaskAsync()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Net_WebClient_DownloadFileTaskAsync_System_String_System_String_) e depois verificar a situação da tarefa se for necessário com [`Task`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

```
using var client = new WebClient());
var tarefa await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync("http://endereco.aqui/arquivo.txt", "arquivo.txt");
```

Ou pode fazer sincronamente se travar a aplicação enquanto baixa o arquivo com [`DownloadFile()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Net_WebClient_DownloadFile_System_String_System_String_):

```
using var client = new WebClient());
client.DownloadFile("http://endereco.aqui/arquivo.txt", "arquivo.txt");
```

Claro que terá que fazer tratamento de exceção e ter outros cuidados, mas a pergunta é genérica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/DownloadFile.cs).

Existem outras técnicas mais antigas mas que não são mais recomendadas.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://meurepositorio.com/file/imagens/a.jpg", "a.mpeg");
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClientDownloadProgressChanged;
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += WebClientDownloadCompleted;
    Console.WriteLine(@"Baixando o arquivo:");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cria um form, insere uma caixa de texto para digitar a url(txtUrl), um botão para iniciar o download(button1), um label para mostrar o quanto foi baixado (label) e uma progressbar(progressBar1) para ver o progresso e insere o código abaixo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startDownload(txtUrl.Text);
}

private void startDownload(string url)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        String nomeArquivo = Path.GetFileName(url);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\Temp\" + nomeArquivo);
    });
    thread.Start();
}
void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        label.Text = "Baixado: " + e.BytesReceived + " of " + e.TotalBytesToReceive;
        progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
    });
}
void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        label.Text = "Download Completo";
    });
}
```

depois é só personalizar para sua necessidade
ps: o código está baixando o arquivo para a pasta c:\Temp\